# WinRT How to check if the application was suspended?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, suspend

I have done the LoadState and SaveState and all works fine.

I just want to check in the page's constructor if I came from suspension or not...
I can do a global bool variable and when I enter to the LoadState to change it's value:

```
bool suspended;

protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    ...

    if (pageState != null)
    {
         suspended = true;
         ...
    }
}

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    if (!suspended)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This works fine, but is there something build in? I think I can check it without global variable...

Comment: Possibly the problem is in the program design - you are trying to do in the page constructor something that should be done in another place, for example, LoadState.

Comment: Maybe, I am using bing maps, and my code onload is to get the current location of the user and to center the map to it's location. The User can pin a pushpin in the map, and when I suspend it, I want to save the pushpin's location so when the user backs, then the pushpin will be shown and the map will center to it's pushpin. The problem is that after it center's to the currents location (which should not occur if we back from suspension). Have any idea how to do it if not with a boolean?

Comment: `The problem is that after it center's to the currents location (which should not occur if we back from suspension)` Why? From user's point of view, there should not be any difference between application start and resuming from suspension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App.xaml.cs `OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)` event can provide you that details. You just have to pass `args` while navigating to particular page. `args` has property called [`PreviousExecutionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.launchactivatedeventargs.previousexecutionstate%28v=win.10%29.aspx)